# The Data in 2 columns layout is not displaying in correct way

Tags: html, css

I have created a page to display posts in two columns However, I noticed that after 2 posts for every alphabet, there is spacing for 3rd post display

[image]

**Here is the code I used:**

For main right column:

```
.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

For internal 2 columns within that main right column:

```
.insideleft {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px 25px 15px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is coming from the fact that the 1st article is higher thant the 2nd to the 3rd goes under the smaller one 1st as it always give priority to the the closest to the top.

One way to go would be to use `display: flex`:

```css
.column.right{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Another way to go would be to use `display:grid`:

```css
.column.right{
   display:grid;
   grid-template-colmuns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.column.right > .insideleft {
  width: 100%;
}
```